# Logarithmic Series Evaluation

Tags: linear-algebra, sequences-and-series, logarithms

I was trying to generate a direct formula for this series but I am not sure whether it is possible to do so.

$$1\ln(1) + 2\ln(2) + 3\ln(3) + 4\ln(4)+\dots+(n-1)\ln(n-1) + n\ln(n)$$

Comment: An asymptotic formula? Or an exact formula?

Comment: What is a direct formula? There is no much reason to assume that there exists a closed-form formula with a finite number of elementary operations, using common function, that equals this expression..

Comment: Please check the edited version

Answer (score 1):

By partial summation:
$$\sum_{k=1}^{n}k\log k = \binom{n+1}{2}\log n-\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}\binom{k+1}{2}\log\left(1+\frac{1}{k}\right)$$
and using the approximation $\log\left(1+\frac{1}{k}\right)=\frac{1}{k}-\frac{1}{2k(k+1)}-\frac{1}{6k(k+1)^2}+O\left(\frac{1}{k^4}\right)$ we get:

> $$\sum_{k=1}^{n}k\log k = \frac{6n^2+6n+1}{12}\log n-\frac{n^2}{4}+O(1).$$

In the $O(1)$-term hides the logarithm of the [Glaisher-Kinkelin constant](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glaisher%E2%80%93Kinkelin_constant).

Comment: What does O(1) denotes here?

Comment: @veer: it is the usual Landau notation. $f(n)=O(g(n))$ means that there exists a constant $K$ such that, for any $n$ big enough, $|f(n)|\leq K\cdot g(n)$.

Comment: Your answer for the asymptotics can also be extracted from the formula (7) [here](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Hyperfactorial.html).

Comment: @O.L.: you're right, but I think it is better to show a two-lines proof than to extract the asymptotics from a much more complicated (and unproven) expression.

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio I gave a *half-line* proof in the comments. Anyway, cheers.

Comment: @O.L.: I disagree, IMHO you did not prove anything, but they are just my two cents, please don't mind.